# Why are the titlebar buttons on the left side in OS X?

Tags: gui-design, layout, mac-os-x

When I moved from Windows to OS X the first thing that I noticed was that the titlebar buttons are on the left instead of right side. It took me some time to get used to it.

**Is there a reason why they put them on the left side?**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: does anyone know if you can move them back to the right?

Comment: Is there a reason they are on the right side in Windows? In my opinion it was at one point an arbitrary decision and the creators likely thought it “felt right”

Comment: I always assumed it was because Jobs was left handed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the original MacOS versions (pre-10), there was a close button in the top left and maximize (if available) in the top right, as shown here:

[image: macos UI]

Putting them together seems like a reasonable choice to tidy up the interface. So, perhaps the real question is why was the close button in the top left corner originally?

My best guess: Mac users use Command-Q (or Apple-Q) to close a program and since the Q key is on the top-left of the keyboard, putting the close button on the top-left of window reinforced its purpose and made for a slightly more consistent experience overall.

Comment: `as shown here` where? I see the image but can't tell what you're referring to.

Comment: @JacobRaihle updated image to show what I was referring to.

Comment: Oh, I was expecting to see the maximize button somewhere, it threw me off.

Answer (score 11):

Steve Jobs was fairly inspired by Xerox's Xerox Star, which was the first to introduce a User Interface in their system.

Demo video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QYvxgNhUwBk

Xerox's Xerox Star was poorly marketed, and hence wasn't well known.

With the inspiration of the Xerox Star, Apple launched Mac OS 1.0 and placed the Window Commands/Actions to the Left, since Xerox too had most of their primary controls on the left.

However, there hasn't been a pure reason as to why where they placed on the left since no one really cared about UX back then, and it was placed in that place for their convenience.

Comment: Your last sentence is completely wrong. The only reason they made a GUI was because they cared about user experience.

Comment: I was referring to the placing of the Window Actions.

Comment: That makes your claim no less wrong. There was consideration of the placement, look, size, spacing, structure, nature, action and goal of everything. They deliberately designed a new paradigm of input and operation. To say they weren't thinking about the user experience of ANY part of what they created is the height of ignorance. These were the founders of thoughts, design and implementation of experiences within  graphical, virtual position based, metaphorical reference, interaction and user experience. They were the revolutionaries of computer operation. Their's was the biggest battle.

Comment: I understand what you're referring to. However, the User Experience part was true to the GUI, not the placement of the elements. Placements of the buttons were made to the likings of the designers and became a norm. If they did research on why the buttons should be placed where they did, there would be a significant research paper on the same. User Interfaces did exist, however User Experience in terms of the UI, did not. As a whole, it did, yes.

Comment: You do realise corporate research sits mostly unpublished, for competitive advantage, right?

Comment: You do also realise public research is often decades and orders of magnitude inferior to that which has corporate finance, backing and resources, too?

Answer (score 5):

Is there a reason they're on the left?

Yes. It's that the ultimate button in this little micro "dialog" box (Window title bar) is the destructive action of closing the window, and Apple determined the ideal order of actions to be from left to right:

|  Destructive ||  Neutral  ||  Constructive  |

Since the button on the far left closes the window, and is therefore the most destructive possible button in a window based GUI OS, it should be on the far left of the Window status bar that is its container when using these rules of lateral action distribution. This fundamental design choice informed the decision to put the close window button on the far left, the other two actions (minimise and maximise) are placed beside it because that's now the area that is the "dialog box action area" of the Window Title Bar.

For a brief while we had the ideal of a super-maximise-to-a-new-screen-space on the top right, double tapping the middle section of the Window Title Bar to minimise and far left being the destructive close button with the minimise and maximise buttons next to it.

But then a (wrong headed) desire to put the download button and iOS sharing button in the top right of Safari seemed to override this ideal across all of Mac OS X, and we lost the normal and rightful maximise button in this little trio. It's been replaced with the fullscreen, new space button. I'm pretty sure this little mess wouldn't have happened under Steve Jobs' watch.

In answer to your original question, yes everything about OS GUI design is intentional, and has reasoning behind both the intentions and the decided design. It's just not always transparent, and sometimes not good intentions, like the desire to transplant the ideas of iOS sharing button placement to Mac OS X.

Comment: I may accept this answer from an Apple marketing guy. You know **reality is different**, it's a legacy design choice. Right or left alignment (from UX point of view) is almost the same (even keeping your reasoning in-place). It's so **arbitrary** that even on **RTL languages** (where everything else is swapped)...they stay on same position. You know...older versions had same layout for buttons. Microsoft decided to move all to the left, Apple to move all to the right (to avoid moving close button, more confusing IMO).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. In fact, I don't. I'm confused.

Comment: LOL! I mean: it's just a case. Marketing guys may put on field psychological patented studies to justify this but it went there by case. If you think about it...you would even keep CLOSE button far from MINIMIZE. You may even want to move them FAR from your sight (top-left). But reality is...it doesn't really matter (and you may do exact same reasoning even from opposite disposition: constructive > neutral > destructive).

Comment: Look up the word "convention" and then you'll understand what the (very) deliberate design of the ordering of [destructive | neutral | constructive] is. They were creating (by design) a convention. They did this based on a blend of inputs and intuitions, along with analysis of prior conventions from the really real world of reality, their experiences, their engagements with others, their origins and their source materials and ideals and intentions.

Comment: Then they adhered to it, throughout the OS and GUI design, very strictly, for decades, for the benefits of new users and those more experienced, and those that learn instinctually. This has nothing to do with language directions, arbitrary choices or whatever else you're attempting to talk about, claim or otherwise.

Comment: And then take some moments (many) to learn the history of design and subsequent design & development of GUIs. There is a direct correlation between the fields of design and UX that most claiming to be UX "designers" seem completely unwilling to recognise. The information within and history of design informs UX as it does UI. For UI is the vehicle upon which UX travels. You seem to have the order wrong, and have become the subject of the first conventions you were exposed to. That's fine. But don't preclude from shallow experience, lack of curiosity and faux beliefs in a "new" fields.

Comment: Omg you believe it! No, I do not stick with one convention but do not rationalize a decision made *a posteriori*. They had to find a marketing reasoning for something already in place. As Apple always does then strictly adhere to that. But that wording is just smoke. No more, no less.

Comment: Your answer doesn't give any references to support the claim you're making. The Far left Close button could be also because it's the most used rather than being the destructive one. Ease of access to the Close button could be another reason for this.

Comment: So your argument is that ease of use is a design criteria superior to convention creation?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti You're more subject to the voices than most. Convention creation is part and parcel of the processes in shaping a new visual design, interaction and experience language. Better known as a GUI. If you knew anything about design you'd understand what I was talking about. If you knew anything about the history of computing you'd understand Apple's take on Xerox efforts wasn't a wholesale ripoff. etc.

Comment: That the thing that came in my mind, that close button should be far from the reach, as most of us are right handed and the top left is the furthest from the reach, give you +1 but open to more answers

Comment: @Confused so far I tried to _suggest_ issues in your _answer_ but I see it's pretty useless so I'll simply spot out **ERRORS**. I'm sorry to spam with so many comments but I hope it will help. Don't refrain to ask for clarification if I'm not clear about something.

Comment: First and most macrospic mistake in your answer is that for 75% you talk about buttons order (Destructive, Neutral, Constructive). Unfortunately **question is about buttons location** (left or right of window caption). You may keep this text for another question (especially because both ordering are good and from UX point of view I'd keep them well separate).

Comment: Second serious mistake is a sort of **prochronism**. You're trying to apply 2015 UX concepts to a 1983 product. Simply these concepts didn't exist at that time. Apple Lisa has been first (commercial) product with a GUI, studies came after (and because) of this. If I can cite you then _"... If you knew anything about the history of computing..."_.

Comment: In 1983 they had more problems with hardware capabilities than with _modern_ UX concepts. GUI itself is revolutionary, micro-design (micro if compared to GUI revolution) was not even seriously considered. BTW your position is opinable, even if you can write pages of text saying almost nothing. Close buttons can be on the left or on the right and now it sticks where it is because of legacy.

Comment: Did they put it on the left because it was there on Xerox prototype? Because of Steve's aesthetic personal taste? Because it's natural flow (left to right) in the west? To save few CPU cycles because an addition instead of a subtraction? **We** don't know and unfortunately it's what OP is asking for. BTW almost every OS I can think about has (now) that button on the right but (in my opinion) it doesn't really matter.

Comment: In [comments](http://ux.stackexchange.com/users/67855/confused) you wrote: _"They deliberately designed a new paradigm of input and operation. [...] These were the founders of thoughts, design and implementation of experiences within graphical, virtual position based, metaphorical reference, interaction and user experience"_. And: _"the ideas formulated in commercial entities and created by them, for them and within their scopes of intent and purpose, ultimately stand the ultimate trial - consumer desirability, satisfaction, enjoyment, reference, reverence and critique..."_.

Comment: What the **** are you serious? Are we talking about design or we have a **marketing** class? I thank you for these funny moments but here I see no room for any discussion...

Comment: It's very simple. And I put it right at the start of my answer. Apple, when designing their GUI, had to come up with a decision based on both reasoning and ease of communication, with sufficient rationale and patterning to become a convention throughout their GUI, to deal with the hierarchy of functions & options presented to users. This informed positioning throughout. Again, since you seem to have missed it, that was, from left to right... Destruction | Neutral | Construction. Hence the close window button was on the left. This also meant the "cancel" option was on the left in dialogs.

Comment: Your premise seems to be that Apple pronounced their decisions based on their source inspiration, not considered thought and design of conventions for information hierarchy and action/function ordering. The preponderance of evidence suggests otherwise, much during the build up to the creation of Lisa. I think you might well be coming at this with prejudice based on your stated opinion and MS Windows exposure in your formative years. Just relax, and rewind through the history of GUI design. There was a lot more thought and design going on than you seem to be willing to give credit for.

Comment: @Confused i respect ur answer alot. would you provide feedback on mine? Did I make too big a jump?

Answer (score 0):

What's the reason the buttons are on the left of the window?

it's because most people are right handed and clicking on the left side feels "wrong'. It's counter-intuitive for something as important as closing an interaction window to be on the "wrong" side. So a user is less likely to close a window by accident.

Where I'm coming from: I used to accidentally close windows on Windows all the time when I was trying to maximize the window because I would move too fast. Clicking "close' on the left side on Mac has forced me to slow down and only close windows if I *really* want to :)